# Magento 2 install extension, extension directory contains all the files without paths.

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, installation

I bought extension and have it downloaded. However, it's not something I was expecting.

The directory contains all the files of the module right in the first directory after unpacking. So it's like `magenest-module-worldpay-and-subscriptions-2.0.0 > [Module files]`.

How do I install the extension? I can't drop the files to the `root`...

Using `Magento ver. 2.1.8`

Comment: What is the directory inside that ? Is that start with app folder or something else?

Comment: OMG. I'm an Magenest Employee. I will support you to install that module. Please provide you skype account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the file of the Module is in the root folder. You have to move all of it to one folder called `root/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName`. Also create the `VendorName` and `ModuleName` folder.

Try to access the `registration.php` file, you will get the name like :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

You can get the `VendorName` and `ModuleName`. After all the file is in the right place. You can run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to install the module. Hope it help!

Comment: I thought it might be that way ;) Was just making sure it is done this way! Thanks for coming back to me!

Comment: So sorry about our fault. Please contact if you have any issue with the module!

Comment: It's fine :) I have seen a couple of modules like this now. I thought it was intentionally left so you can create your own file path. It's up and running now :) Amazing that you came across my post! Thank again

Comment: You are welcome!